# CentOS 6 local update repository and security updates

Tags: centos, security, yum

I know that official CentOS 6 (even 7) update repositories does not provide security information. The consequence is that`yum-plugin-security` plugin and `yum check-update --security` command does not list any updates like on `RHEL` or `OEL` distros.

There is a nice script [generate_updateinfo](https://github.com/vmfarms/generate_updateinfo) which is able to inject missing piece of security information into local `yum` repository. The plugin will then work even on CentOS.

Unfortunately, I have a small issue with it. I'm not sure if the problem is with the script or with how `yum` is working.

How to reproduce the issue (tested on CentOS 6.8, x86_64, but IMO, previous/newer versions suffer from the same issue):

1. first, let's clean everything to start with clean table

> ```
> yum clean all
> ```

2. let's see what security updates are available (the system is not up-to-date)

> ```
> yum check-update --security
> ...
> 56 package(s) needed for security, out of 28 available
>
> kernel.x86_64                                 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-devel.x86_64                           2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-firmware.noarch                        2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-headers.x86_64                         2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> libtiff.x86_64                                3.9.4-21.el6_8                              local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> openssl.x86_64                                1.0.1e-48.el6_8.4                           local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> sudo.x86_64                                   1.8.6p3-25.el6_8                            local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> ```

3. now, let's install e.g. `squid` package

> ```
> yum install -y squid 
> ...
> Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6 will be installed
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ====================================================================================================================
>  Package           Arch               Version                          Repository                              Size
> ====================================================================================================================
> Installing:
>  squid             x86_64             7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6              lp-centos-6-x86_64-updates             1.8 M
>
> Transaction Summary
> ====================================================================================================================
> Install       1 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 1.8 M
> Installed size: 6.3 M
> Downloading Packages:
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64.rpm                                                           | 1.8 MB     00:00
> Running rpm_check_debug
> Running Transaction Test
> Transaction Test Succeeded
> Running Transaction
> Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
>   Installing : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 1/1
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 1/1
>
> Installed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6
>
> Complete!
> ```

4. I would like to test update of the package so let's try to downgrade it first

> ```
> yum downgrade -y squid
> ...
> Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5 will be a downgrade
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6 will be erased
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ====================================================================================================================
>  Package           Arch               Version                          Repository                              Size
> ====================================================================================================================
> Downgrading:
>  squid             x86_64             7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5              lp-centos-6-x86_64-updates             1.8 M
>
> Transaction Summary
> ====================================================================================================================
> Downgrade     1 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 1.8 M
> Downloading Packages:
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64.rpm                                                           | 1.8 MB     00:00
> Running rpm_check_debug
> Running Transaction Test
> Transaction Test Succeeded
> Running Transaction
>   Installing : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64                                                                 1/2
>   Cleanup    : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 2/2
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64                                                                 1/2
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 2/2
>
> Removed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6
>
> Installed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5
>
> Complete!
> ```

5. let's rather double-check what it is installed

> ```
> rpm -qa | grep -i squid
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64
> ```

6. at this moment, I would expect that when I check security updates again the `squid` package should be newly listed but it isn't

> ```
> yum check-update --security
> ...
> 56 package(s) needed for security, out of 28 available
>
> kernel.x86_64                                 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-devel.x86_64                           2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-firmware.noarch                        2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-headers.x86_64                         2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> libtiff.x86_64                                3.9.4-21.el6_8                              local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> openssl.x86_64                                1.0.1e-48.el6_8.4                           local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> sudo.x86_64                                   1.8.6p3-25.el6_8                            local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> ```

7. let's see what squid errata are installed on the system. This is somehow weird. From the above, I can see the squid was downgraded to `squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64` (`CEBA_2016__1412 bugfix`) but `squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64` (`CESA_2016__1573`) seems to be still marked as installed

> ```
> yum updateinfo list all | grep squid-3
>
> i CESA_2011__1791 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.1.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0122 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.2.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0470 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.3.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0557 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__1290 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-9.el6_3.x86_64
> i CESA_2013__0505 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-16.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2013__0985 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-18.el6_4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2013__1396 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-19.el6_4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2014__0048 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-20.el6_5.x86_64
> i CESA_2014__0597 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-20.el6_5.3.x86_64
> i CESA_2014__1148 Important/Sec. squid-3.1.10-22.el6_5.x86_64
> i CEBA_2014__1446 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-29.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2015__1314 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-9.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2016__0896 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-16.el6.x86_64
> i CESA_2016__1138 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2016__1412 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64
> i CESA_2016__1573 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64
> ```

8. When I try to get information for that errata there's nothing

> ```
> yum update info CESA_2016__1573
> --- NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING ---
> ```

9. When I try to list all errata but grep that one I can see it

> ```
> yum updateinfo info all | grep CESA_2016__1573 -B3 -A8
> ===============================================================================
>   Moderate CentOS squid Security Update
> ===============================================================================
>   Update ID : CESA_2016__1573
>     Release : CentOS 6
>        Type : security
>      Status : stable
>      Issued : 2016-08-04 12:51:39
> Description : Moderate CentOS squid Security Update
>    Severity : Moderate
>   Installed : true
> ```

I would like to point out that I tested this scenario (downgrade/upgrade) on RHEL6 and it works. I also tried to install old version of `squid` package directly to avoid downgrade/upgrade sequence but the result was also the same. And the issue is not related to `squid` package only. Basically, I can reproduce the issue with any package. I also tried to clean `yum` cache after package downgrade but it doesn't help.

Any idea what could be wrong?!? Why is it marked as installed when it is actually not?!? When testing on RHEL6, I can see it is not installed and then, it is included in the list of packages to be updated.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Shouldn't step-8 be `yum updateinfo CESA_2016__1573` and not `yum update info`?

Comment: What happens if after step-5, but before step-6, you run `generate_updateinfo.py` again?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, there's no change when 'updateinfo' file is generated again. The issue I see is that I don't understand why yum and the security plugin is 'thinking' that the latest available version of squid package is installed but it actually isn't. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to easily debug the issue...